# How to use bootstrap grid system overlaying a map

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, google-maps, responsive-design

I'm trying to overlay several panels over a full screen google map web page. I want to use mdl grid system to keep the design simple and quick.

Here is My html (there is some pseudo code):

```
<div #map>
  <map></map>
</div>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
         <div class="map-panel"></div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
#map{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
}
.overlay{
  margin-top: 10%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

This solve My need for responsive web site and simplicity. However, I can't scroll or interact with the map (the grid system overlay the map and mask the ability to click on it)

map-panel takes around 25% of the screen so I'll have plenty of room to interact with google maps, I have several elements like map-panel.

I also tried:

```
#map{ 
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; 
 left:0; 
 z-index:1; 
} 
.overlay{ 
   margin-top: 10%; 
   position: relative; 
   z-index: 0;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
}

.map-panel{
    z-index: 3;
}
```

But My panel disappear below the map.

How can I overlay a common grid system on top of google maps and still keep the ability to interact with google map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without code to test it becomes difficult do give you a definitive answer - but the basic concept you're missing is the HTML.

You want to position an outer parent/wrap that is the `relative` `position` to the `absolute` `position` of the map and the overlay.

## HTML

```
<div class="outer-wrap">
    <map></map>
    <div class="overlay">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9">
                <div class="map-panel"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.outer-wrap {
    /* Must have some sort of height and width so that
    inner children (map and overlay) can position 
    themselves to it */
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
map, div.overlay {
    /* This stretches the these elements to the edges of 
    the closest element upwards in the DOM with a relative 
    positioning (in this case it's the .outer-wrap) */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}

map {
    /* needs to be lower than the overlay */
    z-index: 1;
}
div.overlay {
    z-index: 2; /* Needs to be higher than the map */
    opacity: .8; /* Just to keep the map is visible */
}
```

Hopefully this sets you in the right direction, happy coding! : )

Comment: Thank, however, My map should be full page

Comment: That is out of the scope of your original question... but to achieve that, you can use the `vw` and `vh` measurements. They refer to the percentage of the view-port of the screen. if you substitute `width: 500px;` for `width: 100vw;` and `height: 500px;` with `height: 100vh;` that should give you a full screen parent element to fill your map with on any size screen. [This link](http://tutorialzine.com/2015/05/simplify-your-stylesheets-with-the-magical-css-viewport-units/) should give you some extra info on `vw` and `vh` / viewport measurements

Comment: If my solution worked, please select my answer as the solution.

Comment: The thing is, when you overlay the map like this you can still see it but you can't interact with it (opacity keep the map visible but you can't click on it) the point of the question was about keeping the map functionality while overlaying it with responsive functionality

Comment: Worked with a small change:

Comment: Worked with a small change: additional  `.map-panel{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 60vh;
  z-index: 3;
}`  solve it